# apply hover simultaneously to different part of text with css

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a (CSS-)way to apply the hover state to a part of my HTML text when another part is hovered over, the two parts sharing the same CSS class.

I have a bunch of text in HTML, divided into words. Each word is linked to a CSS class; two different words can be linked to the same class.

By example, if I take three words and two classes (classA, classB),

```
word1, word3 -> classA
word2 -> classB
```

I will write the following HTML code :

```
<span class=classA>word1</span>
<span class=classB>word2</span>
<span class=classA>word3</span>
```

My problem : I want to change the appearance of a group of words sharing the same class on mouse over.

I tried :

```
.classA {
    color: red;
  }
.classA:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
```

... but when the mouse goes over "word1", "word1" is highlighted, but not "word3" which shares the same class ("classA").

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**, you cannot do that with CSS only except if you go for the solutions I've shared with you below.

Use the adjacent selector to apply the `:hover` effect at the same time

```
.classA:hover + .classB + .classA {
    color: blue;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v98uS/)

But unfortunately this will only work if you `:hover` the first group element, as you cannot go back with CSS, the second way to do is use a wrapper element but again, this will be limited if you are having only 2 combination of classes where you want to apply styles to a single type of class.

```
.wrapper_class:hover .classA {
   color: blue;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/v98uS/1/)

Comment: Thank you : the second 'solution' is particularly impressive. Can you explain the statement "this will be limited if you are having [...] type of class". I don't understand it.

Comment: @suizokukan I just meant that say you have 3 groups, but you've a single wrapping element, so when you want to have this effect only when you hover that particular word and other element having a common class, it will fail when you have 2 combinations :) http://jsfiddle.net/v98uS/2/ if you've only what you've provided, than this thing will suffice

Answer (score 2):

```
.classA:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

This code applies only to elements that have `class=classA` AND are under the mouse..
I think it would be simpler to use Javascript:

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('classA');
var i = 0;
while(i < span.length){
    span[i].onmouseover = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < span.length){
            span[i].style.color = 'blue';
            i++;
        }
    }

    span[i].onmouseout = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < span.length){
            span[i].style.color = 'red';
            i++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fa7d0/Bt8eN/1/**

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a pure CSS solution : Javascript is not allowed.