# fastest way to change texte appearance in a QTextEdit object

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

For a Python3/PyQt4 project, I'm looking for the fastest way to change the text appearance of several words in a QTextEdit object. The text is not written in HTML (it's a pure text string), is read-only and is made of several words. Each word has a special 'attribute' defined in my code, defining its appearance when this word is hovered over. 
**The appearance of all words sharing the same attribute must change when one of these words is hovered over.**

I need speed since :

- I did more or less the same program but the the words' appearance changed when the user *clicked* on them and I guess my code is too slow to be used with hover events. (see details below)
- It's a Python project based on PyQt4, not a C++ one based on Qt.

Any help would be appreciated !

MORE DETAILS :

I can see two ways to achieve my goal :

(1) Write my text in the editor, detect which word the mouse "flies over", get the other words to be highlighted and **painfully** select them, one by one, inserting some HTML code to modify their appearance. It's the **painfully** part that I find too complex and too slow : is there a fastest way to do this ?

(2) Writing my text as an HTML one and work with the CSS since a QTextEditor can use them. Alas, the [easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287056/apply-hover-simultaneously-to-different-part-of-text-with-css) can't work. But perhaps is it possible to "re-load" the CSS of the text and use a more clever trick ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering is it even possible to get the word under mouse cursor from the QTextEdit.

You said the text cannot be edited, so I maybe the QTextEdit is not the best possible widget for this job. Create your own widget and draw the text by yourself. Then you know the word positions so finding the word under the mouse is easy. And when some attribute is activated or deactivated, you can redraw only the affected words.

Comment: [It's possible](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11791-QTextEdit-get-word-under-the-mouse-pointer) and I must use QTextEdit.

Comment: Why do you must use QTextEdit? I'm pretty sure using QTextEdit is not the fastest solution to the problem you described.

Comment: My problem is not linked to the question "where is the word under the mouse's cursor ?" (I know how to handle this) but to the fact that I want to quickly modify pieces of my text. I keep your idea in mind, though, but I need the power of the QTextEdit objects.

Comment: I understand that you can get word under the mouse. But in the question you say that the text is read only and no HTML is used. So what I didn't understand is what features of the QTextEdit are really needed.